# templating from PHP array data

Tags: php, json, templates, mustache

So I have built a two-dimensional php array which contains results from two tables. The tables have one common column (time) which I have sorted them by. If the subarray contains information from one table, I will send it off to one template (mail), if it is from another table (event), I will send it off to another template.

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["entity"]=> string(10) "mail" 
                            ["time"]=> string(19) "2015-02-05 05:10:26"
                            ["title"]=> string(0) "what's up?" }         
           [1]=> array(3) { ["entity"]=> string(5) "event" 
                            ["time"]=> string(19) "2015-02-05 03:16:54"
                            ["title"]=> string(15) "asfasggasdgasdg"  } 
           [2]=> array(3) { ["entity"]=> string(10) "mail"
                            ["time"]=> string(19) "2015-01-11 14:24:08"
                            ["title"]=> string(24) "lunch?" } }
```

My question is how to handle templates in php... I have used them with JSON data, particularly mustache.js, but this does not seem compatible with php. When I have template previously, It has been with ajax data, so the data was typically already converted to JSON.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to handle this? I am a somewhat newbie programmer and not sure what to do here. Should I convert the data to JSON? Or does anyone have a recommendation for a php templater that would word for this?

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you fetch this data through ajax, use JSON. If you have this data directly available in your page, just use array notation directly or use a foreach loop.
It depends on how you want to parse it in your HTML

Comment: ok, thanks. yeah, not ajax in this instance.

Comment: Mustache for PHP: https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php